# how to update a field without change auto-now field?

Tags: python, django

In a loop and automatically, that is, I always check all users once every 10 minutes, and I may need to update a bool field from them
How can I not change my current field when I update that bool field ?

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey ... 
    last_activity = models.DateTimeField(_("Last Activity"), auto_now=True)
    joined = models.BooleanField(_("Joined in Default Channel"), default = False)
    ...
    ...
```

i want to update `joined` field without change `last_activity`.

how can  i do?

Comment: you can use `Client.objects.filter(user=user).update(joind=True)`. `update` method doesn't call save so `last_activity` won't be updated to now

Comment: Exactly, thank you @ElginCahangirov

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `Client` object, you can specify the fields to update with the `update_fields=…` parameter of the [**`.save(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) of your model:

```
c1 = …  # (some client)
c1.joined = True
c1.save(update_fields=['joined'])
```

If you want to update `Client`s with a single query (or in bulk), you can work with [**`.update(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update):

```
c1 = Client.objects.filter(pk=some_pk).update(
    joined=True
)
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime field is updated when .save() method is called, you can update needed field(s) using .update method.